# Routing from a SSR page to a CSR page without briefly displaying the SSR page in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, csr

I have a page that is rendered on the server with getServerSideProps. It looks similar to one of my pages to which i can route from the said SSR page. The issue i am facing is with routing from SSR to a similar looking CSR page.

Upon clicking the routing button the content of SSR page that i am routing from gets flashed for less than a second then the page navigates to the CSR page. Is there a way to avoid this brief flash ? Thanks in advance.

I can't use loaders during navigation.